# using a placeholder with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join

I'm attempting to avoid any SQL injection vulnerabilities by substituting with my params on a join.

```
Category.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = ?", params[:Dept])
```

This attempts to execute the query with a question mark in it, instead of substituting it for the param.  What is the proper way to do this?

EDIT:

Query needs to return this:

```
SELECT categories.* 
FROM "categories" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes 
ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = 86
```

not

```
SELECT categories.* 
FROM "categories" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes 
ON incomes.category_id = categories.id 
WHERE incomes.dept_id = 86
```

Very different results!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use the [sanitize_sql_array](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Sanitization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-sanitize_sql_array) method. It is, however, a protected method so on your Category model you could do:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.income_for_dept(dept)
    Category.joins(sanitize_sql_array(["LEFT OUTER JOIN incomes ON incomes.category_id = categories.id AND incomes.dept_id = ?", dept]))
  end
end
```

Then you would call it like:

```
Category.income_for_dept(params[:Dept])
```

Ruby provides some other methods, if need be, to get at that method without making a class method in Category.

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
Category.joins(:incomes).where(:incomes => { :dept_id => params[:Dept] })
```

And check out the [Rails documentation for joining tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables).

Comment: Thank you, but this does not meet my query standards.  This will place a condition on the where clause, not on the join.  I need to return all categories, regardless if there is a match or not.  I need it to specifically filter by `AND incomes.dept_id`, otherwise this query does not work.