# unknown class: Fixnum Rails MySQL query - inserting variable breaks my search

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, fixnum

I had a query which was working just fine:

```
@schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id])    
@schedule_tasks = ScheduleTask.select("s.*, t.*, t.*, d.*, st.*").from("schedule_tasks st").
            joins("left join schedules s ON s.id = st.schedule_id").
            joins("left join tasks t ON t.id = st.task_id").
            joins("right join days d ON d.id = st.day_id").
            order("d.number, t.name").
            group_by{|d| d.number}
```

I had to refine my search to only schedule_tasks with a specific schedule_id, so I edited the second line to:

```
joins("left join schedules s ON s.id = st.schedule_id AND s.id = ?", @schedule.id).
```

This has cause the following error:

```
unknown class: Fixnum
```

The error goes away if I take out the group_by - but I need that, and I have tried hard coding in the number instead of @schedule.id and that does not work either, a google search does not reveal a lot of details on this error.

Comment: Is the generated query correct and are you getting results?

Comment: Until I insert the schedule_id into line 2 the query works fine, but it now fails during the query.

Comment: `@schedule = Schedule.find(params[:id) ` is missing a `]`

Comment: I think you're mixing up a 'join' together with a 'where'... the where clause should be separate than the join clause. maybe something to the event of `joins("left join schedules s ON s.id").where("s.id = ?", @schedule.id)` ...

Comment: I need the where clause on the join because I need to return all the days.  If I do a separate where clause, then the right join on the days table doesn't work anymore.

Comment: At a complete guess, one of the columns you are returning is shadowing an active record method. Try reducing the set of returned columns until the error goes away.

Comment: I am running into the exact same issue (need a where clause in my join). Did you end up fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here from Google, I used plain string interpolation to fix this issue. This method is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions), so make sure you type check your variables before using them.

In this case I would do

```
@schedule_id = @schedule.id
.
.
.
joins("left join schedules s ON s.id = st.schedule_id AND s.id = #{@schedule_id}")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14420925 looks like we have a lot of "sanitize.." methods

Answer (score 0):

Rather than following [learning_to_swim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355030/3982001), which as noted is at risk of SQL injection, couldn't you cast your `@schedule_id` to a string?

```
@tasks = ScheduleTask.joins("left join [...] s.id = ?", @schedule.id.to_s)
```

Comment: It didn't work. Doesn't this return `operator does not exist: ? integer` error?