# getting SQL injection warning from brakeman due to ruby interpolation in join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, sql-injection

I am using ruby interpolation which is working perfectly as per `ActiveRecord` but as per `Brakeman` its Sql Injection warning. My code:

```
user_room_ids = [10000,20000,30000]
tmp_query = "left outer join users u on u.emp_id = emps.id join user_rooms ur on (ur.id IN (#{user_room_ids})) join practices_user_rooms pwr on (pur.user_room_id = ur.id)"
all_emps = Employee.joins(tmp_query)
```

due to interpolation `#{user_room_ids}` I am getting Sql Injection warning, which I want to resolve.

Comment: Tried as follow as well:  "join war_rooms wr on (wr.id IN (?))"  and all_emps = Employee.joins(tmp_query, user_room_ids)  but getting InvalidStatement error with this solution.

Comment: Why is your Query in string.Can you please post your models. So that we can help you create a better Active Record query

Comment: @praga2050 Its a old legacy system and now we are using brakeman to find out the health of application. I posted a small section of "tmp_query" even, as its a string of 10 lines although. So can't go away from string I think.

Comment: I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14420698/using-a-placeholder-with-joins/48878681

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
user_room_ids = [10000,20000,30000]
tmp_query = "left outer join users u on u.emp_id = emps.id join user_rooms ur on (ur.id IN (#{user_room_ids})) join practices_user_rooms pwr on (pur.user_room_id = ur.id)"
all_emps = Employee.joins(ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, "#{tmp_query}"))
```

This should be working fine. For more details, please refer my Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50154062/need-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-rails3/50171073#50171073)